# Term for fraction of economic value earned?

Tags: labor-economics, marxism

Is there a term for the fraction of economic value earned by a person in their labor that is due to their creation?

For example, a car factory laborer who's work creates:

Economic value created = $500,000

Income Paid = $50,000

Would have a value of 0.1

At the other end of the spectrum, the CEO might be

Economic value created = $2,000,000

Income paid = $1,500,000

Fraction = 0.75

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be looking for the phrase '[wage share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wage_share)' or 'share of labour compensation'.

Wage share:

> The wage share (or labor share) is the ratio between compensation of employees (according to the system of National accounts) and one of the following variables:
>
> 1. gross domestic product at market prices
> 2. gross domestic product at factor cost
> 3. net domestic product at factor cost (domestic income at factor cost)

Here is some [US data on share of labour compensation](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/LABSHPUSA156NRUG).

Comment: Sometimes it is also called the labor share.

Comment: Thanks, that's more or less what I'm interested in. Is there somewhere you can get this data per job type, per industry or per company?

Comment: @SomeGuy I am afraid I don't know the answer to that. My guess would be that you cannot because you may be able to infer costs from that and companies try to keep such information secret.